# How could I hire a programmer to add a small feature to an OSS project?

Tags: open-source, hiring

I'd like [a feature added to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671290/show-a-characters-unicode-codepoint-value-in-eclipse), as a small plug-in, but:

- It's a bit niche, so not high demand. So if I post it as a feature request it's unlikely to be followed-up.
- Still, I'm sure someone else would find it handy.
- I'm a programmer, but I don't know Java, and I don't think it's currently worth my time learning Java just to code this.

What might be a good way to find a programmer who could code such an Eclipse plug-in, and pay them to do the job?

My example is specifically about Java and Eclipse, but what might be an answer to this question in general terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here: [Hacker News Thread](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1759653)

To summarize it briefly:

- [Hacker News Freelance Google Spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets2.google.com/ccc?key=tk7rUIb-2aPdk_5gFJEodCA&hl=en#gid=0)
- Craigslist
- [FreelanceSwitch](http://jobs.freelanceswitch.com/)
- [Odesk](http://www.odesk.com/)
- [eLance](http://www.elance.com/p/landing/buyerD2.html)
- [Authentic Jobs](http://www.authenticjobs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

When I have small tasks like that, easy to define, easy to manage, I use either [Rent A Coder](http://www.rentacoder.com) or [oDesk](http://www.odesk.com) to find high skilled developers. With a preference for the last one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a local with a physical presence (which will save you time and money in communications) then I would consider having a look at where the Eclipse plugin programmers hang out.  There is most likely a mailing list where you could ask for assistance.  You might even get it for free if others need the same.

I also know that JBoss have a whole division which does Eclipse plugins if you need brand names and consulting and all.